# How to access properties with different names in a collection?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, mean

I have a collection with a structure as follows:

[image: The structure of collection]

How can I access properties with different names in a collection?

I have tried doing it like this:

```
for(i=0;i<$scope.users.length;i++)
{
    console.log($scope.users[i].google|facebook.email);
}
```

Comment: Add your code here not screens shots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this,

```
if($scope.user[i].hasOwnProperty('facebbok')){
    console.log($scope.user[i].facebook.email);
}
if($scope.user[i].hasOwnProperty('google')){
    console.log($scope.user[i].google.email);
}
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty